# linux pacemaker - prevent split brain

Tags: linux, pacemaker

since using CentOS 7, we switched from a regular heartbeat setup to pacemker.

Mainly we have IP resources that are active on one node and switch to a second node if a failover happens. Also we execute some scripts in case of a failover. Nothing special.

For resources to always start on the primary node, i use

```
pcs constraint location Cluster_IP prefers server1=master-server
```

I also use

```
pcs resource defaults resource-stickiness=INFINITY
```

to prevent resources moving back after failover.

This works fine for me, if the master fails (hardware failure for example).

Since its not a problem for me if the failover takes some time, i would like to implement some kind of delay in case of a short split brain.

Before doing anything, the slave should wait ~2 Minutes, before it takes over, in case the master is reachable again in this ~2 Minutes.

I was wondering, what would be the best way to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've never set a token timeout in Corosync to anything above 10 seconds, but you could try increasing/setting the `token` value in your `corosync.conf` to `120000` (120 seconds in milliseconds). `token` should be defined in the `totem{}` section of your `corosync.conf`; `man corosync.conf` for more detail.

That should prevent Corosync from declaring a node dead for 120s when the network flakes out.

Comment: @sebkoe: This should work, I quickly tested it on a test cluster with a single ring. I just added a ring to my test cluster, and it took twice as long, so try setting `token` to half your desired time if you're using `rrp_mode: passive`.

Comment: Thanks, it now worked. Maybe i did something wrong in my first try

Comment: @sebkoe perhaps you forgot to restart Corosync? Either way, don't forget to mark your answer ;)

Answer (score 1):

You can change the monitor interval of the resource with `op monitor interval=Ns` where `N` is the number of seconds, and then set the `migration-threshold` on the resource to `2`. Keep in mind with a setting of `120s` you could see a total delay of 120-240s depending on when the initial failure occurs in the monitoring interval.

There are other caveats to this, in that the failure counter applied to `migration-threshold` does not reset on success. To do that you would also need to set `failure-timeout` or manually intervene.

With `op monitor interval=120s`, `migration-threshold=2`, `failure-timeout=121s` and your `resource-stickiness` setting, you would need to test to ensure this provides the functionality you expect and how the failure counters behave when the original master recovers. It could require manual intervention but I'm not 100% certain on that